# Ignite Spring + Ignite SQL ClassCastException

Tags: java, spring, ignite

Every time I try to use the Ignite Spring API and Ignite SQL API interchangeably, I get class cast exceptions or "no sql table found for xxxx"

This happened because I created a cache using ignite spring and tried to consume the data using Ignite SQL API, or vice-versa:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableIgniteRepositories("local.teste.is.api.repositories")
public class SpringAppCfg {

    @Bean
    public Ignite igniteInstance() {
        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

        cfg.setIgniteInstanceName("springDataNode");
        cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
        cfg.setClientMode(true);

        ...

        // Defining and creating a new cache to be used by Ignite Spring Data
        // repository.
        CacheConfiguration ccfg = new CacheConfiguration("SQL_PUBLIC_SAMPLETYPE3");

        // Setting SQL schema for the cache.
        ccfg.setIndexedTypes(Integer.class, SampleType.class);

        cfg.setCacheConfiguration(ccfg);

        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);

        IgniteCache cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(ccfg);

        SqlQuery sql = new SqlQuery(SampleType.class, "true");

        try (QueryCursor<Entry<Integer, SampleType>> cursor = cache.query(sql)) {
              for (Entry<Integer, SampleType> e : cursor)
                System.out.println(e.getValue().toString());
            }


        return ignite;
    }
```

**SampleTypeRepository:**

```java
package local.teste.is.api.repositories;

import org.apache.ignite.springdata.repository.IgniteRepository;
import org.apache.ignite.springdata.repository.config.RepositoryConfig;

import local.al40.is.api.entities.SampleType;

@RepositoryConfig(cacheName = "SQL_PUBLIC_SAMPLETYPE")
public interface SampleTypeRepository extends IgniteRepository<SampleType, Integer>  {

    public SampleType getSampleTypeBySampleTypeId(Integer id);

}
```

**Everything using ignite Spring works, including saving and reading data:**

```java
public class Application {

private static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext dataCtx;
private static SampleTypeRepository repo;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    dataCtx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

    // Explicitly registering Spring configuration.
    dataCtx.register(SpringAppCfg.class);
    dataCtx.refresh();

    repo = dataCtx.getBean(SampleTypeRepository.class);

    System.out.println(repo);

    SampleType s = new SampleType(1, "teste");

    repo.save(s.getSampleTypeId(), s);

    System.out.println(repo.getSampleTypeBySampleTypeId(1).getSampleTypeName());
```

This happens if I create an Ignite SQL table via DDL and try to consume it via Ignite Spring, giving me a ClassCastException like "...ignite.IgniteRepositoryImpl#123456 cannot be casted to SampleType.class". This leads me to believe that this is a problem related to serialization. It also gives me "no sql table found for xxxx" if I create the table via Ignite Spring and tried to query it. Has someone tried to integrate these two perspectives? The examples I found online assume only caches created using Ignite Spring, and Ignite's documentation makes it seem that it this interchange is possible and transparent. However, apparently, it is not, unless I'm forgetting something.

Best regards,

Carlos Costa

Comment: Can you show how `SampleTypeRepository` type is defined?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I solved my problem. Thanks everyone for your help. In an attempt to further clarify my rather complex doubt, I will write the following guidelines that should be taken into consideration if one is trying to use Ignite SQL and Ignite Spring interchangeably:

**Option 1) Create caches via Ignite Spring:**

a) Clearly define the cache name in the repository class:

```
...
@RepositoryConfig(cacheName = "My Cache Name")
public interface SampleTypeRepository extends IgniteRepository<SampleType, Integer>  {

    public SampleType getSampleTypeBySampleTypeId(Integer id);

}
```

b) Define the cache and indexed when configuring your Ignite instance in the Spring app:

```
...
CacheConfiguration ccfg = new CacheConfiguration("My Chache Name");

// Setting SQL schema for the cache.
ccfg.setIndexedTypes(Integer.class, SampleType.class);

config.setCacheConfiguration(ccfg);

Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(config);
...
```

c) Query it, but be aware that for some reason the SQL table name is "SampleType" not "My Cache Name". I don't know ehy, but it seems to be some default behavior that I did not find explicitly in the Ignite Spring documentation. Otherwise you may get "no SQL table found for ":

```
...
IgniteCache cache = ignite.cache("My Chache Name");

        SqlFieldsQuery  sql = new SqlFieldsQuery("select * from SampleType");
        try (QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(sql)) {
              for (List<?> e : cursor)
                System.out.println(e.get(1));
            }
```

**Option 2) Create caches via SQL DDL:**

a) Create your SQL table/cache by clearly defining the cache_name, key_type and value_type, using fully qualified package names for the classes corresponding to the key and value types:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SampleType(SampleTypeID int, SampleTypeName varchar, PRIMARY KEY (SampleTypeID)) WITH "cache_name=mycachename, key_type=java.lang.Integer, value_type=local.teste.is.api.entities.SampleType";
```

b) To insert data, via ignite Spring works like a charm using the API methods shown in the documentation. However, inserting via DDL or JDBC you need to clearly identify the _KEY attribute (an hidden attribute apparently :P):

```
INSERT INTO SampleType(_KEY, SAMPLETYPEID, SAMPLETYPENAME) VALUES(?,?,?)
```

Then, I think you can use these APIs interchangeably.

Best regards,
Carlos Costa

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing `Cache.Entry` instead of `Map.Entry`? Unfortunately I can't see your import lists but I suspect you can replace latter with former, get your code to function.

Comment: You're right, that was my fault, sorry. However that was not the main problem. The problem was in fact serialization and the way sql tables must be created. I will reply to my own question regarding a way to define sql tables that can be used accross ignite kv api, ignite sql api and ignite spring, without classcastexceptions, nullpointers, or no "sql table found for"...

Thank you for your help. That solved the initial part of my problem indeed :)

Comment: @CarlosCosta I suggest you split your following up problems in separate tickets, so that they can be answered separately according to guidelines.

Comment: I managed to understand and solve the problem. I gave a detailed answer to my own question, because it may help others in the future. i just think that some of the steps to solve the problem could be explicit in the documentation (e.g., the _KEY attribute, the default SQL table name created via Ignite Spring, the need for the fqdn of the class, the need to explicitely define a cache name in the sql ddl). or maybe I just missed something between the several attempts, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to review the Apache Ignite SQL API documentation. The given example on the OP is missing some details that others would need in order to follow along and understand your situation (Spring config excerpts).

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/sql-api#configuring-queryable-fields

To expose data created in a cache API call to SQL API queries, Ignite needs to know which data should be exposed as fields. Either annotations or Spring configuration are available as documented, to create the necessary QueryEntity objects, and map cache fields to SQL columns.